# Rails get route pattern in controller / filter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

say I have such a route:

```
 put '/:fair/:user/checkin', :controller => :fair, :action => :checkin
```

end

Is there a way to get in the controller action the string `'/:fair/:user/checkin'` (the pattern that was matched by Rails router)?

Comment: Why do you want such a thing? Might help us answer.

Comment: I understant the purpose is obscure. But the idea is that I want to get the order in which params are in the URL. In above case: :fair first, :user second, which params do not carry.